# What tags are needed for questions about domains?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

At the moment we have two tags with `domain` in their name:

- [domain](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) with 46 questions and no tag wiki
- [coded-value-domain](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coded-value-domain) with 39 questions and a tag wiki

and there is no tag specifically for range domains.

Do we need more than a single tag related to domains?
If so, how many and which tags related to domains do we need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a single tag for domain that covers both range and coded-value would be sufficient.

Comment: However I would not be opposed to creating [tag:value-range-domain] and having just that and coded value. That would imply burninating domain though - I don't think we need all three.

Comment: There seems to be no diverging opinions from your answer so I'm proceeding to implement [tag:coded-value-domain] as a synonym of [tag:domain].